# Laravel - Elegant way to query the latest date on a database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have products and prices table (Temporal Data).
what is the best approach for getting the latest price of a specific product?
here's the basic structure of my two tables:

```
products table:
-ID
-name

prices table
-ID
-product_id
-amount
-effective_datetime
```

Product Model:

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Price', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Price Model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
}
```

Im currently using this code to get the latest price of a product:

```
 $product->prices->sortByDesc('effective_datetime')->first()->amount
```

As you can imagine, I have to call that long line all over my application just to get the latest price of a product. is there a better way?

My idea is to create a queryScope on my Price model like this:

```
public function scopeLatest($query)
{
        return $query->sortBy('effective_datetime', 'desc')->first();
}
```

and Call

```
$product->prices->latest()->amount
```

but laravel is throwing an error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest()"

Comment: Try `$product->prices()->latest()->amount`.

Comment: @StuartWagner - Thank you, my queryScope is now working.. I've overlooked the '()' on prices.\

Comment: Cool, glad it works :)

Comment: Yes, I also had to change $query->sortBy('effective_datetime', 'desc')->first() to $query->orderBy('effective_datetime', 'desc')->first();

Comment: Ah, yeah, I missed that.

Comment: @StuartWagner Please write an answer so this question can be officially marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply scopes to a relationship, you have to call them on the relationship's method (rather than its dynamic property) to allow query chaining. Try this:

```
$product->prices()->latest()->amount
```

*(Originally commented)*

Answer (score 1):

In your case it would be ideal to have an accessor:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    $this->prices()->sortBy('effective_datetime', 'desc')->first()->amount;
}
```

Now you can use it like `$product->price`.

Comment: Instead of sortBy you can use latest('effective_datetime')

Comment: Tried accessor like this, added the column in protected $appends variable, and it shows result as expected. But, when I log the queries, it calls another query for each item, so when I call `Item::paginate(25)`, it is doing 1 + 25 queries.